# Safari does not show .gif loader

Tags: jquery, html, safari

I'm trying to show a .gif loader when my page is loading because it take a lot of time with to load because i do a lot of call to the Google API

It works on Mozilla / Chrome but not on Safari and IE

Here is my code :

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    // Lorsque notre contenu est chargé
    $('.loader').click(function() {
        $("#load").show();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow');
        disableScroll();
        $('html,body').css("overflow","hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
.loading {
    background: transparent url("data:image/gif;base64,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") no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: none;" id="load">
<p class="span_loader" style="font-size: 20px;">Veuillez patienter pendant le chargement de la page...<br/>Merci.</p>
<p class="loading"></p>
</div>
```

i just add the .loader class to an a element to active my loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Height & Width

```
.loading {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```